# Перемещение view элемента относительно других обьектов

Tags: java, android

Мне нужно задать движение, например кнопки, от края ConstraintLayout до центра TextView.
Какие есть альтернативы  этому способу, например задаю координаты по y?

```
public Point viewLocatedAt(View v) {
int[] location = new int[2];
v.getLocationOnScreen(location);
int x = location[0];
int y = location[1];
return new Point(x, y);
} 

***

public void run() {
f001 = viewLocatedAt(ConstraintLayout).y - (textButton1.getHeight()/2);
LineY_1.clear();
LineY_1.add(f001); //добавление в ArrayList
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Анимации это всегда некий гемор. Что могу вам порекомендовать? Посмотрите в сторону [Transition Animation](https://developer.android.com/training/transitions). Там вы можете создавать анимационные сцены, что позволит вам создавать более мощные и адаптивные под макет анимации. [Здесь](https://habr.com/ru/post/243363/) еще есть неплохая статья на эту тему.

Второй механизм который я вам предложу еще более интересный, а если использовать ***Android Studio 4.0+*** то и проще это [MotionLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/motionlayout). Он позволяет задавать начальное и конечные состояния экрана и какие-то `keyFrame-ы` в течении самой анимации. С помощью этого механизма можно перестать писать полотна кода и делать реально крутые анимации. Вот тут есть очень понятный [codeLab от Google](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/motion-layout/index.html?index=..%2F..index#0).

В противном случае вам придется писать полотна кода вроде того что вы сейчас написали. Я не уверен, что это прям ответ на ваш вопрос, но мне кажется это может решить вашу проблему.

Comment: Спасибо, это вроде то что нужно.  https://code.tutsplus.com/ru/tutorials/creating-animations-with-motionlayout-for-android--cms-31497 может кому-то еще понадобится